# How can I display data on input tag using ajax?

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, jspinclude

Hi:) I want to display data on "input" when select "select option".
I included jsp page, which have "input" tag, so using ajax send data to included jsp page.

Here's my code. Name is "new_order.jsp"

```
<script>
$('select#product').change(function() {

        var param = "code=" + $('#product').val();

        $.ajax({
            url : 'add_products/add_products.jsp',
            contentType : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
            data : param,
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : 'html',
            success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
            }
        });
    });
...
</script>
<body>
<table class="add_products_tb table" data-toggle="table">
                    <tr>
                        ..
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        ..
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            ..
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>
                                        <select name="product" id="product" class="selectpicker" data-width="150px">
                                            <option data-hidden="true">-Select-
                                        <%
                                            try {
                                                query = "select * from new_product";
                                                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                                                while (rs.next()) {
                                                    product_code = rs.getString("product_code");
                                        %>
                                            <option value="<%= product_code %>"> <%= product_code %>
                                        <%
                                                }
                                            } catch (SQLException e) {
                                                out.println(e);
                                            } finally {
                                            }
                                        %>
                                        </select>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                        <jsp:include page="add_products/add_products.jsp"  />
                    </tr>
                </table>
</body>
```

The Next Code. This is included jsp, "add_product.jsp"

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select#product').change(function() {
                        <%
                            product_code = request.getParameter("code");
                            int size = 0;
                            try {
                                query = "select * from new_product where product_code='"+product_code+"'";
                                rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
                                while (rs.next()) {
                                    size = rs.getInt("sizes");
                        %>
                                    $('#size').val("<%= size %>");
                        <%
                                }
                            } catch (SQLException e) {
                                out.println(e);
                            } finally {
                            }
                        %>
    });
});
</script>
...
<body>
                        <td>
                                <input type="text" id="size" class="form-control" name="size"  />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                <input type="text" id="color" class="form-control" name="color"  />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                <input type="text" id="price" class="form-control" name="price" value="0" readonly  />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                <input type="text" id="quantity" class="form-control" name="quantity" value="1"  />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                                <input type="text" id="total_price" class="form-control" name="total" value="0" readonly  />
                        </td>
</body>
```

The Problem is, I want to receive the data, "code", from "new_order.jsp" and display the data on "add_product.jsp", but it doesn't display on the page. I also have debugging the page, the data is sent to "add_product.jsp", but didn't display on input.

I changed a variable "product_code", placed on "add_product.jsp" script, to value, not jsp variable but special value in DB. So, there is data on "input"! Just One....

I want to display using jsp variable. Please help me...T.T Thanks.

Comment: you should not really have this java code in your jsp.  Consider moving it to a servlet (or some framework strusts, stripes etc.)

Comment: @ScaryWombat Thank you for your comment, but I don't know about servlet.. Can I ask you what is the framework strusts?